# merge con dinámico?

Tags: sql-server

Hola buena tardes tengo el siguiente `Merge`, pero quisiera hacerlo dinámico hay posibilidad de lograrlo?

La tabla `[DB1].[dbo].[TCXC]` se va llenar con diferentes tablas de otras BD por eso es la tabla destino esa no cambia sin embargo la tabla ORIGEN CAMBIARA en el ejemplo esta la `[DB2].[dbo].[TCXC]` posterior puedes ser: `[DB3].[dbo].[TCXC]`, `[DB4].[dbo].[TCXC]`, etc...

La parte que requiero sea dinamica es que mediante parametro pueda cambiar la base de datos de la tabla origen

```
MERGE INTO [DB1].[dbo].[TCXC] AS DESTINO
USING
   (SELECT * FROM  [DB2].[dbo].[TCXC]) AS ORIGEN 
   ON ORIGEN.[idCXC] = DESTINO.[idCXC] AND ORIGEN.Empresa=DESTINO.Empresa AND ORIGEN.Tienda=DESTINO.Tienda
WHEN MATCHED AND 
    (
        DESTINO.[idCXC] <> ORIGEN.[idCXC]
    OR  DESTINO.[NumCliente] <> ORIGEN.[NumCliente] 
    OR  DESTINO.[Total] <> ORIGEN.[Total] 
    OR  DESTINO.[TotalPagos] <> ORIGEN.[TotalPagos] 
    OR  DESTINO.[Saldo] <> ORIGEN.[Saldo] 
    OR  DESTINO.[UltModif] <> ORIGEN.[UltModif] 
    OR  DESTINO.[Empresa] <> ORIGEN.[Empresa] 
    OR  DESTINO.[Tienda] <> ORIGEN.[Tienda]
    ) 
THEN UPDATE
   SET 
      DESTINO.[idCXC] = ORIGEN.[idCXC],
      DESTINO.[NumCliente] = ORIGEN.[NumCliente],
      DESTINO.[Total] = ORIGEN.[Total],
      DESTINO.[TotalPagos]=ORIGEN.[TotalPagos],
      DESTINO.[Saldo]=ORIGEN.[Saldo],
      DESTINO.[UltModif]=ORIGEN.[UltModif],
      DESTINO.[Empresa]=ORIGEN.[Empresa],
      DESTINO.[Tienda]=ORIGEN.[Tienda]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
   VALUES(
      ORIGEN.[idCXC],
      ORIGEN.[NumCliente],
      ORIGEN.[Total],
      ORIGEN.[TotalPagos],
      ORIGEN.[Saldo],
      ORIGEN.[UltModif],
      ORIGEN.[Empresa],
      ORIGEN.[Tienda]
   )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: que quiere decir dinamico?? puedes explicar mejor la idea???

Comment: La tabla [DB1].[dbo].[TCXC] se va llenar con diferente tablas de otras BD  por eso es la tabla destino esa no cambia sin embargo la tabla ORIGEN CAMBIARA en el ejemplo esta la [DB2].[dbo].[TCXC] posterior puedes ser:
[DB3].[dbo].[TCXC],
[DB4].[dbo].[TCXC],
etc...

Comment: edite la pregunta aclarando que en la parte dinámica te refieres a poder cambiar la base datos del origen de la tabla.

Comment: Puedes usar [sp_sqlsexec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) para ejecutar la consulta almacenada en una varible varchar